# Java FTP Upload Completed but not returning

Tags: java, ftp

Good day. I have imported org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP to my project and I faced some issues when upload the zip file to FTP.
When it uploads small file(<100MB), it works fine. But when it comes to larger file (>500MB), it will stops there, without returning and execute the remaining operation, even it the file is transferred to the server.
And how the function / FTP acknowledge when the transfer is done? Is there anyway to check it?

```
public class zipFTP
{
public boolean uploadFile(String ht, String usr, String ps, String fpath, String uploadloc)
{
    FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    writeLog nLog = new writeLog();
    String channel = "FTP";
    boolean completed = false;
    //client.setBufferSize(1048576);
    client.setControlKeepAliveReplyTimeout(300);

    //System.out.println(client.getBufferSize());
    try
    {
        nLog.writeToLog(dumptoFTP.filename, channel, "Uploading...");

        client.connect(ht);
        client.login(usr, ps);
        client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

        fis = new FileInputStream(fpath);
        completed = client.storeFile(uploadloc, fis);
        //client.completePendingCommand(); //to complete the transaction entirely
        if(completed) 
        {
         if (dumptoFTP.isSysLog)
            System.out.println("File uploaded");
            nLog.writeToLog(dumptoFTP.filename, channel, "File uploaded");
        }

        fis.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        if (dumptoFTP.isSysLog)
            System.out.println("Upload failed");
        nLog.writeToLog(dumptoFTP.filename, channel, "Upload failed");
        nLog.writeToLog(dumptoFTP.filename, channel, e.toString());
    }
    finally 
    {
        try
        {
            if(client.isConnected())
            {
                client.logout();
                client.disconnect();
            }
        } 
        catch (IOException ex) 
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return completed;
}
```

}

Comment: what do you mean `not returning` is it blocked somewhere and if so where?  Basic debugging.

Comment: as I said, if it's transferring small file, it works. But when it comes to larger file, it will stop there, even if the file is fully transferred.

Comment: where does it stop?

Comment: Here `completed = client.storeFile(uploadloc, fis);`

Comment: so it looks like it is blocking on the ftp server - not enough space ? Timeout? - can you check the ftp servers logs e.g. /var/log/xtransfer?

Comment: definitely there's enough space.
Will check the server log file. Thanks for the tips

Comment: @ScaryWombat no significant error stated. But after I `setBufferSize(1024*1024)`, the transfer was done within minutes. And I do appreciate your guide, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up, `setBufferSize()` does the trick